# Spring @RequestParam Type mismatch exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So i have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "uid", required = true) Long uid) {
    // logic to play with uid
}
```

What type of exception does Spring throws when the `uid` type is incorrect, for example `String`?
From documentation it's seems like [ConversionFailedException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionFailedException.html) but this is not caught on an exception handler for the respective class.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {ConversionFailedException.class,})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
public ModelAndView wrongParameterType(ConversionFailedExceptione,HttpServletRequest request){
    //log and things
}
```

I also tried with [TypeMismatchException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException.html) which is caught, but I'm confused because from docs this is thrown when trying to set a bean property.

Could you clarify which type of exception is thrown and when?

Comment: Can't you just look at the stack trace to find the exception thrown?

Comment: After a couple of tests, `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` is always thrown.

Comment: either check you console or modify your handler to catch Exception.class and print a logger or something

Comment: You can catch the value in string first. then check that , is it long or is it int or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you were talking about, if you provide 'uid' as String & you are expecting ConversionFailedException.
But, ConversionFailedException usually occurs when there CAN BE the fitting converter and java is unable to find that converter.

If you still didn't get it, here is the  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511761/conversionfailedexception-persisting-a-dbobject-but-retrieving-returns-a-linked)  once asked by some person where you can understand the ConversionFailedException.

And yet, after testing, you can check that there is the MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException with the **root cause** as *NumberFormatException* which clearly signifies that java responded to your conversion but was unable to convert *String* to *integer*